# YouTube difference between FavoritesCount from statistics (API call) and YouTube Analytics Dashbord Favorites Metrics?

Tags: youtube-api, favorites

I am using following API call for retrieving FavoritesCount    : -

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$video_ID}?v=2&alt=json

I am parsing above API's response to retrieve Favorites Count from statistics .

But, when I log in to YouTube account and go to Analytics of that video  : -

I can see following metrics when i click on Favorites on dashbord -

- Favorites Net Change
- Favorites Added
- Favorites Removed

I am confused between above Three metrics count (values) from Analytics Dashbord and 
Favorites Count getting from API call (statistics).My question is what is the difference or connection between these metrics from Analytic DashBoard and fav count from API call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Youtube Analytics:

favoritesAdded
The number of times that users marked a video as a favorite video.

favoritesRemoved
The number of times that users removed a video from their favorite video lists.

And the Favorites report (formerly part of Community in Insight) displays a summary of how many users favorited your content, how many removed it from their favorites, and the net change.

http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=1715146&guide=1714169&page=guide.cs

And in the YouTube Data API V2

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:statistics

favoriteCount:

The favoriteCount attribute specifies the number of YouTube users who have added a video to their list of favorite videos. The favoriteCount attribute is only specified when the  tag appears within a video entry.